# easier way to make listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

i have to make a listview in which there are two elements to be displayed vertically.
i know that to use the default adapter given with android there can only be one array and one text resource...ie if i am using android.R.layout.simple_list_view then there is only one text resource.
To make a custom Listview i am doing the following:

1. making a xml layout file for each element of the listview
2. extending a custom adapter class which extends the baseadapter
3. in the getview method of the custom adapter class i am inflating the view for each element and then returning with the info i want the listview element to have from an array which i have passed as a constructor to the custom adapter class.

this seems very tedious because there are several instances where i have to make listview where sometimes there are three text elements in each listview element and sometimes 2 text elements in each listview element.

is there an easier way to do the above.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such simple layout, I'd suggest you to just use a `LinearLayout` and 2-3 `TextView`s (or any view you need, even an horizontal `LinearLayout`). Nothing will beat that simplicity. There's no need for a `ListView` in that case.

Comment: i guess i did not make it clear in the question. there is a whole list which i have to display and each (ListView)element may have 2 /3 textviews.

Comment: OK. Sorry about the misunderstanding :) Then it seems that you're doing pretty much the standard procedure. If you use similar adapters repeatedly on different lists then I would suggest you to make your own private library and import it every time you need it. Not much more to say, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider creating a generic, reusable ListView layout file that is loaded up with all the various elements you need (which, hopefully is a concise few). You could default as many of those elements in the layout XML file with android:visible="false" and then programmatically toggle the visibility.

Why can't you just reuse the adapter? It's got plenty of loading/unloading methods associated with it.

Yes, what Aleadam is saying; if you only have a couple of things why use a ListView? TextView would seem a much quicker way to prototype data display!